# Does this look infected?

Tags: fermentation, wort

Trying out my first batch of home brew... it's a central smash IPA one gallon recipe boiled over on me, so this is a very small 3/4 gallon batch ha. I see a lot of floating green. Nothing's moving anymore it's been about two weeks in the glass carboy. Does this look normal?[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything I see there looks normal.  Green floaties, just hops. Clean surface, no pellicile starting. Some bubbles, c02 still being produced.

Comment: Do you think the bubbles mean it is not quite done fermenting until CO2 is no longer being produced?

Comment: @JordanFields indeed. It can take several weeks for some fermentations to hit a terminal gravity. If bubbles are forming, something is producing a gas, usually c02 and from yeast.

Comment: So you would say it is not ready to be bottled?

Comment: @JordanFields only checking the gravity will tell for sure.

Comment: Don't have a hydrometer :/ do you think it would be Madge to bottle possibly prematurely?

Comment: @JordanFields well without knowing how much fermentable are left you risk a bottle bomb. If your going to bottle blind I recommend using plastic soda bottles, not glass.

Answer (score 2):

Judging fermentation by how long you see activity in the airlock is unpredictable. You saw some activity, which is a good sign.

Did you happen to get any hydrometer readings?

That green stuff floating around are hops that are still suspended.

At this point, I would give it a taste. If it tastes like flat, almost-beer, you're in good shape. Make sure you sanitize the siphon before doing this.

Comment: Awesome. I did not get any hydrometer readings. I just got a starter kit from northern brewer from my fiancé for my birthday didn't come with a hydrometer. I figure if I like this I can upgrade

Answer (score 0):

My wife saw this picture and immediately said,  "Looks aren't everything".

It doesn't look bad,  I would probably judge it by smell. If it stinks you might have a problem. If it smells like beer,  get it into secondary and see what happens.

Comment: Does fermented beer usually look this way? Literally my first batch ever. The airlock stopped moving after 6 days.